# logically prove: $R$ is Relation $\to R\subseteq\operatorname{dom}(R)\times \operatorname{cod}(R)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, relations, alternative-proof

I must logically prove following (with $R$ set or class):

> $R$ is Relation $\to R\subseteq\operatorname{dom}(R)\times \operatorname{cod}(R)$

**Definitions:**

$R$ is Relation if $\forall x \in R: \exists y,z: x=(y,z)$

$\operatorname{dom}(R):=\{x|\exists y:(x,y)\in R\}$

$\operatorname{cod}(R):=\{x|\exists y:(y,x)\in R\}$

**UPDATE**: I thinked following:

$$\begin{align}x\in R &\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge (y,z)\in R \wedge (y,z)\in R\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge\exists z:(y,z)\in R\wedge\exists z:(y,z)\in R\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge\exists y:\exists z:(y,z)\in R\wedge\exists y:\exists  z:(y,z)\in R\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge\exists y:y\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\wedge\exists z:\exists  y:(y,z)\in R\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge\exists y:y\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\wedge \exists z:z\in \operatorname{cod}(R)\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge z\in\operatorname{cod}(R)\wedge\exists y:y\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\\
&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge z\in\operatorname{cod}(R)\wedge y\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y\in\operatorname{dom}(R):\exists z\in\operatorname{cod}(R):x=(y,z)\\&\leftrightarrow x \in \operatorname{dom}(R)\times \operatorname{cod}(R)
\end{align}$$

**UPDATE** (@Reese): 
$$\begin{align}x\in R \to\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge (y,z)\in R \wedge (y,z)\in R\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge\exists z:(y,z)\in R\wedge\exists z:(y,z)\in R\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge\exists y:\exists z:(y,z)\in R\wedge\exists y:\exists  z:(y,z)\in R\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge\exists y:y\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\wedge\exists z:\exists  y:(y,z)\in R\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge\exists y:y\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\wedge \exists z:z\in \operatorname{cod}(R)\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge z\in\operatorname{cod}(R)\wedge\exists y:y\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\\
&\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge z\in\operatorname{cod}(R)\wedge y\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\\&\leftrightarrow\exists y\in\operatorname{dom}(R):\exists z\in\operatorname{cod}(R):x=(y,z)\\&\leftrightarrow x \in \operatorname{dom}(R)\times \operatorname{cod}(R)
\end{align}$$
Is it correct?

Comment: What are your definitions? Specifically, define "relation" "domain" and "codomain" carefully. The answer should be pretty quick from your definitions, but depends on how they are phrased.

Comment: I edited my post!

Comment: Interesting, I've heard codomain = range but not necessarily image. This usage is the opposite.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers Why was this flagged as unclear?

Comment: The statement you seem to be trying to prove is false. If $R$ is the set $\{(0, 0), (1, 1)\}$, then $R$ is a relation with domain $\{0,1\}$ and codomain $\{0,1\}$. But $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} = \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$ is not the same as $R$. Your proof breaks down on the first line; it is not the case that $x \in R$ iff $\exists y : \exists z : x = (y,z)$. That would make $R$ the set of all ordered pairs. The next two steps are also invalid - you should check your proof system to see what steps are allowed.

Comment: I edited my post, Is it now correct?

Comment: @Marios Your proof is excessively and bizarrely complicated. I have edited my answer to provide a proof in your formal system. Does that proof work for you?

Comment: Also, the point of @Reese's comment is that you're proving a bidirectional when only one direction of it is in fact true.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be a relation.

Let $(x_0,y_0)\in R$. Then $x_0\in \operatorname{dom}(R)$ and $y_0\in \operatorname{cod}(R)$, so $(x_0,y_0)\in \operatorname{dom}(R)\times \operatorname{cod}(R)$. Thus $R\subseteq\operatorname{dom}(R)\times \operatorname{cod}(R)$.

---

You can tell that what you've currently written is wrong because as Reese and Josh pointed out, the statement is $R\subseteq\operatorname{dom}(R)\times\operatorname{cod}(R)$, **not** equality. Your proof proves equality and therefore cannot be right. Your proof is also much more complicated than it needs to be. This works.

\begin{align}a\in R
& \to\exists b:\exists c:a=(b,c)\\
&\to (b,c)\in R\\
&\to\exists y:(b,y)\in R\\
&\to b\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\\
&\to\exists y:(y,c)\in R\\
&\to c\in\operatorname{cod}(R)\\
&\to (b,c)\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\times\operatorname{cod}(R)\\
&\to a\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\times\operatorname{cod}(R)
\end{align}

Comment: I think that your proof is not (logic) formal.. it is naive!

Comment: @mle I don't know what you're talking about. This is a formal proof.

Comment: @StellaBiderman, mle is right, your proof is clar (+1) but for my question is so naive. I edited my post...

Comment: @Marios yes, your edit looks right. Next time, if you want an answer in a particular formal language, you should specify which language you want it to be written in. Thee are many different proof systems in which one can write a so-called "formal proof."

Comment: @StellaBiderman, thanks, I thinked that there are errors because existential quantifier distributes over disjunction, but not conjunction..!?

Comment: @Marios yes they do, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_passage_(logic)

Comment: @StellaBiderman, read please the comment of Reese!!!

Comment: @Stella The other direction is not correct, the line saying $x_0 \in \mathrm{dom}(R)$ and $y_0 \in \mathrm{cod}(R)$ implies $(x_0,y_0) \in R$ is wrong.

Comment: @JoshChen Derp.... that direction isn't even true >.> fixed.

Comment: @Marios My proof is fixed, and also explains how to do the proof in the formal system you are using.

Comment: @mle Got my letters confused, that's fixed now.

Comment: @mle I added one more line to account for it. My proof is still shorter and simpler than the one in the OP. The proof in the OP is also **wrong** in addition to being poorly written.

Comment: @mle You're really not making much sense. Proof style and field of mathematics have almost nothing to do with each other. Proof style is a reflection upon the context and demands of the person teaching the course/reading the paper. I have given picture proofs in logic courses before, and all manners of informal proofs.