# Why does $\exists$ distribute over conjunction here?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169663/logically-prove-r-is-relation-to-r-operatornamedomr-times-operatornam) I used:

$$\small \exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge (y,z)\in R \wedge (y,z)\in R\leftrightarrow\exists y:\exists z:x=(y,z)\wedge\exists z:(y,z)\in R\wedge\exists z:(y,z)\in R$$
But why does $\exists$ distribute over conjunction here?

Comment: What makes you think it is possible?

Comment: ok, I edited my post!

Comment: It doesn't distribute under conjunction. This step is incorrect.

Comment: @Reese, Why? I editey my another post!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, $\exists$ does not distribute over conjunctions, but in your specific case it (mostly) does because:

$\exists y : \exists z : (x = (y,z) \land (y,z) \in R \land (y,z) \in R )\Leftrightarrow$

$\exists y : \exists z :( x = (y,z) \land x \in R \land x \in R )\Leftrightarrow$ (Null Quantification!)

$\exists y : \exists z : (x = (y,z) \land \exists z : x \in R \land \exists z : x \in R) \Leftrightarrow$

$\exists y : \exists z : (x = (y,z) \land \exists z : (y,z) \in R \land \exists z : (y,z) \in R)$

though please note that this last statement is not quite the same statement as:

$\exists y : (\exists z : x = (y,z) \land \exists z : (y,z) \in R \land \exists z : (y,z) \in R)$

which is what the result would be of distributing the existential over the conjunction. In other words, it *looks* like you are distributing the existential over the conjunction, but it's actually a little different from that.